# Using REST: Security invalid error with SharePoint Add-in

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, json

Currently getting an error when using REST to upload a file within SharePoint. Error reads "The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."

From what I have researched, this is a Form Digest issue when using a custom master page within a SharePoint Add-in.

I've read that it may be possible to use cross domain references so that SharePoint can run as expected (the code works fine with no custom master page).

Any ideas how to construct this in the correct format? Or is there a way to retrieve the request digest and use it within the add-in, (I get 403 errors when trying to retrieve using REST).

Answer (score 0):

Every REST api call with POST method must have a request digest value passed (or almost every).
Here is the example of how to get it:

```
// pass target site collection url or leave blank to get current site collection digest
function getDigest(url){
        return $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' },
            url: "{0}/_api/contextinfo".format(url || _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl)
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.FormDigestValue;
        });
}
```

Dont forget to send it with your request

```
...
headers: {
    ...
    'X-RequestDigest': <digest_value_here>
    ...
}
...
```

Code will look something like this:

```
getDigest("/sites/whatever").then(function(digestValue){
   return $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 
                'accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' 
                'X-RequestDigest': digestValue
            },
            url: "/sites/whatever/_api/whatever"
        });
}).then(successCallback, failCallback);
```

You can also refer here (especially if RequestExecutor is needed to provide cross-doman calls): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. i'll give this a go and post my findings. (Just to note, currently using "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val,)

Comment: jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() is fine as long as you are making requests to the current site collection (since it has current digest in it).

Comment: Also be aware that request digest is valid for 24 minutes (default value).

Comment: The SharePoint add-in should be making requests to the current site collection it resides in, however still receiving the "security validation" error message?

Comment: The alert(itemid) stops showing after it is added below the following line of code:  
`var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer, i);
            
UpdateFormDigest(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl, _spFormDigestRefreshInterval)
            addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {
                alert(itemid);`

Comment: looked into this in a bit more detail, added in code and receive 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'format' of undefined or null reference? This stems from within the getDigest function?

Comment: try to changing this line url: `"{0}/_api/contextinfo".format(url || _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl)` to something like `url: (url || _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl)+"/_api/contextinfo"`

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved - after numerous checks and searches within the code, using `clearfields()` within `initializepage()` function (within bootstrap modals) was causing the form digest to change. Once commented out, the REST functionality worked.

Hopefully this solution solves a headache with anyone else searching for answers!

Thanks a lot Alex K for your input, also very helpful.